# delete activity from recent, when the application is running

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I would turn the flags *noHistory* and *excludeFromRecents*, when the activity is already running.
For example, when google chrome opens in incognito mode notification is generated,
that when you click on it eliminates all activities of the stack and removed from recent. I want to do something like this, with some activities of my app.

**Edit:**
The solution  proposal by David Wasser works, but my problem is a bit more complicated.
This is my manifest.xml

```
...
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityRecive"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>



    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityPasswordToIncognito">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityIncognitoMode1">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityIncognitoMode2">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityIncognitoMode3"
    </activity>
...
```

ActivityRecive: begins as a result of intent. I want this activity is excluded from the stack and exclude From recent. ActivityRecive can launch ActivityPasswordToIncognito.

ActivityPasswordToIncognito: "normal" activity. ActivityPasswordToIncognito can launch ActivityIncognitoMode(X).

ActivityIncognitoMode(X): they can launch ActivityIncognitoMode(x+1) and I want that when the user exit from incognito mode are deleted from recent and stack.

The problem is that the root Activity(ActivityRecive) used android: excludeFromRecents="true", then the all activity in task is excluded from recent. I have tried using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to launch  ActivityPasswordToIncognito, but not work.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the bejaviour you are seeing? What isn't working? Be more specific.

Comment: @DavidWasser I want to emulate the operation of the flag noHistory and excludeFromRecents, when the activity is already running. As similar as I know is to finish() the activity. But this does not delete from recent and if it is the last of the stack is recreated. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your entire application go away, and leave no trace in the "recent tasks" list, you should be able to do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
intent.putExtra("finish", true);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your root activity, add the following code to `onCreate()`:

```
super.onCreate();
if (getIntent().hasExtra("finish")) {
    // Need to finish now
    finish();
    return;
}
... rest of your onCreate() code...
```

This will clear the stack back to your root activity (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER) and then the root activity will exit. Because the root activity is launched with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` it shouldn't show up in the list of recent tasks.

NOTE: This will only work if your root activity stays in the activity stack when it launches other activities in your application (ie: doesn't call `finish()`).

Comment: Thank You! In my case fakerootactivity begins as a results of receiving a intent.action.send. fakerootactivity launch rootactivity with flag cleartop and excludefromrecent. Then rootactivity creates other activities (for example activityX), Then to clean launch rootactivity with  "finish" in the intent from activityX.  But this does not delete from recents (show activityX in recent but when open  then start rootactivity). I add ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=LAUNCHER in manifest.xml for rootActivity

Comment: Please post your manifest. I'm not understanding this completely.

Comment: Still not sure I understand completely, however please try the following: add `android:taskAffinity=""` to `<activity>` definition for `ActivityRecive` and use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when launching `ActivityPasswordToIncognito` from `ActivityRecive`. This will ensure that `ActivityPasswordToIncognito` is the root of a new task and that task should show up in the recent tasks list.

Comment: It does not work and do not know why. ActivityPasswordToIncognito stays in recent tasks list.  If instead of using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT ` working properly